# SVN Diff - Discard 'origin branch (A)' differences and add 'destiny branch (B)' differences

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have 2 branches, let's say A and B and I applied a SVN diff to them. Let's say I'm in branch A at them moment, I'd like to remove all the code that's in A and not in B and then add all the code that's in B to A.

After this process branch A and B would be pretty much 100% equal.

Is there a way of doing these in SVN?

I want to do it this way because I want to keep A's history (e.g. all the commits that have been done there)

Thank you.

Comment: Why make it complicated? Throw A away and copy B to A. Unless there's some constraint you're not sharing, in which case, please [edit] and tell us.

Answer (score 0):

The problem to use the log from branch *A* but the contents from branch *B* is rather specific so there is not a pure Subversion solution to it.

I also see the risk that keeping the history but not the files with the respective changes may cause confusion in the long run. Say you fixed a bug on branch *A* but not on branch *B* and then you do what you plan to do there would still be a log entry that says the bug was fixed on a buggy file.

Nevertheless, I would go for a simple approach and checkout branch *A*:

```
svn checkout <YOUR_REPO>/branches/A wc
```

Next, I'd delete everything except the `.svn` folder from `wc`.

To move all of *B*'s files over, you can use Subversion's export command:

```
svn export --force <YOUR_REPO>/branches/B wc
```

Then comes the hard part, in which you will have to `svn add` files not present in *A* but in *B* and `svn rm` files present in *A* but not in *B*. Some tricks using the command line may help but that's beyond the scope of this question. TortoiseSVN is also up to the job, you'll just have to check and uncheck a lot of files.

It should be mentioned that svn properties will not be transferred. I'm not aware of any way of doing so. So you should double check them.

As a last step, `svn commit` your changes. Hopefully with a very descriptive log message that makes clear that all and any earlier log messages should be disregarded.

The much better alternative would be to throw the log away (or rather: throw *A* away) and copy *B* to *A*:

```
svn rm <YOUR_REPO>/branches/A
svn cp <YOUR_REPO>/branches/B <YOUR_REPO>/branches/A
```